# MongoDb, Yii2, Active Record: $or needs an array

Tags: php, mongodb, yii2, mongodb-query

everyone.

I have composed the following query in **mongo** and tested it using **robomongo** - it worked.

```
db.customers.find({$or: [
    {emailaddress: /.*test.*/},
    {address: /.*test.*/},
    {firstname: /.*test.*/}
]})
```

Now I am trying to implement this query in Yii2 using Active Record:

```
$fields = [];
$search = '/.*' . $search . '.*/';//in $search was the word 'test'

foreach($this->searchFields as $field) {
    $fields["$field"] = "$search";
}
$text_search = [ '$or' => ['$search' => $fields]];

$query = $query->where($text_search);

$provider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
]);
```

It worked before adding $or, and now it gives me an error:

```
"name": "MongoDB Exception",
"message": "Cannot run command count(): exception: $or needs an array",
"code": 20,
"type": "yii\\mongodb\\Exception",
```

Printing $test_search using print_r gives me:

```
Array
(
    [$or] => Array
    (
        [$search] => Array
        (
            [emailaddress] => : /.*test.*/
            [address] => : /.*test.*/
            [firstname] => : /.*test.*/
        )
    )
)
```

If I remove `'$search' =>` and leave only

```
$text_search = [ '$or' => [$fields]];
```

it gives me:

```
{
    "recordsTotal": 0,
    "recordsFiltered": 0,
    "data": []
}
```

Does anyone know how to make this query working in Active Record? Please give me some ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing that each "document" is meant to be a member of the [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) array as it's own condition. You are making a single document with the different keys.

Also you cannot use a regular expression from a "string" like that. Rather use the [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) query operator, with just the string of the expression.

Instead do:

```
$search = '.*' . $search . '.*';
$text_search = [ '$or' => [] ];

foreach($this->searchFields as $field) {
    array_push( $text_search['$or'], [ $field => [ '$regex' => "$search" ] ] );
}

$query = $query->where($text_search);
```

Also when you compare to JSON then output as JSON encoded for debugging purposes:

```
echo json_encode( $text_search, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT ) . "\n";
```

You can't go wrong then as you will see if it looks the same or not:

```
{
    "$or": [
        {
            "emailaddress": { "$regex": ".*test.*" }
        },
        {
            "address": { "$regex": ".*test.*" }
        },
        {
            "firstname": { "$regex": ".*test.*" }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, my friend,. It worked and you explained me my mistakes - the best answer I couldn't even expect, I really appreciate that.